# @FormParam does not work with GET method-RestEasy

Tags: java, jsp, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I am learning web services with Resteasy

i am doing a simple basic example of rest easy using `@FormParam`.
My example works when request method is `POST`
but does not work when i change the request method to`GET`

```
@Path("/form")
public class FromParamService {

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    public Response addUser(
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("age") int age) {

        return Response.status(200)
            .entity("addUser is called, name : " + name + ", age : " + age)
            .build();

    }


    @GET
    @Path("/adduser")
    public Response addUser1(
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("age") int age) {

        return Response.status(200)
            .entity("addUser is called, name : " + name + ", age : " + age)
            .build();

    }
}
```

output with GET is

> addUser is called, name : null, age : 0

output with POST is

> addUser is called, name : Abhi, age : 23

The jsp for GET request is

```
<html><body>       

<form action="rest/form/adduser" method="get">
    <p>
        Name : <input type="text" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Age : <input type="text" name="age" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
</form></body></html>
```

And Jsp for POST request is

```
<html><body>


<form action="rest/form/add" method="post">
    <p>
        Name : <input type="text" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Age : <input type="text" name="age" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
</form></body></html>
```

My question is why i am not able to get values using GET request with `@FormParam`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default behavior of forms for GET requests, is to put the key/values in the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). If you look in the URL bar, you might see something like

```
http://localhost:8080/app/form/addUser?name=something&age=100
```

As opposed to POST request, this oart `name=something&age=100` will actually be in the body of the request, not in the URL. This is where `@FormParam` works, as it is for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data type, as the body. GET request should have no body, so the data is send in the URL.

To get the GET request to work, we need a different annotation that works with query strings. That annotation is `@QueryParam`. So just replace the `@FormParam("name")` with `@QueryParam("name")` and same for the age