# WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public java.lang.String, should not consume any form parameter(UPDATED)

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I have that error when i execute my getCustomers() method in Postman. The problem is that for some reason executes the method getOrder() isntead of just getCustomers(), if i let it uncommented. I have searched about this issue but i was not able to find anything that worked in my case. Any help will be very apreciate.

**Error:**

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A HTTP GET method, public java.lang.String com.something.JerseyProjectConnectionToDB.App.getOrder(java.lang.String), should not consume any form parameter.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.something.JerseyProjectConnectionToDB.App, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@3ea75b05]}, definitionMethod=public java.lang.String com.something.JerseyProjectConnectionToDB.App.getOrder(java.lang.String), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=date, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:371)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:346)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5206)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

**App.java**

```
@Path("/app")
public class App {

    @GET
    @Path("/getCustomers")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<CustomerPOJO> getCustomers() {
        return CustomerDAO.getAllCustomers();
    }

/*
    @GET
    @Path("/getOrder")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getOrder(@FormParam("date") String date){
        return CustomerDAO.getOrder(date);
    }
    */
    }
```

**CustomerDAO.java**

```
public class CustomerDAO {

    public static List<CustomerPOJO> getAllCustomers(){
        List<CustomerPOJO> customerList = new ArrayList<CustomerPOJO>();
        CustomerPOJO customer = null;
        try(Connection conn = DBConnection.createNewDBconnection()){
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from customer");
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                customer = new CustomerPOJO();
                customer.setCustomer_code(rs.getInt(1));
                customer.setCustomer_name(rs.getString(2));
                customer.setCustomer_adress(rs.getString(3));
                customer.setCustomer_age(rs.getInt(4));
                customerList.add(customer);
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
        return customerList;
    }

public static String getOrder(String pattern){
        List<OrderShipmentPOJO> orderList = new ArrayList<OrderShipmentPOJO>();
        OrderShipmentPOJO order = null;
        
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String orderListToString = null;
        
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = null;
            
        try(Connection conn = DBConnection.createNewDBconnection()){
            date = simpleDateFormat.parse(pattern); 
            logger.info(date);
            
            if(CheckDate.execute(date)) {
                String query = "select customer.customer_name, product.product_title, order_shipment.order_date\r\n"
                        + "from customer, product, order_shipment, order_shipment_has_product\r\n"
                        + "where order_shipment.order_code = order_shipment_has_product.order_code \r\n"
                        + "and (order_shipment_has_product.product_code = product.product_code\r\n"
                        + "and (order_shipment.customer_code = customer.customer_code\r\n"
                        + "and (date(order_shipment.order_date) = '?')))";
                
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setDate(1, (java.sql.Date) date);
                
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                
                while(rs.next()) {
                    order = new OrderShipmentPOJO();
                    order.setCustomer_name(rs.getString(1));
                    order.setProduct_title(rs.getString(2));
                    order.setOrder_date(rs.getDate(3));
                    orderList.add(order);
                }
                rs.close();
            } else {
                return "You have inserted a date that dont exist, try again";
            }
            
            orderListToString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderList);
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            return "Unparseable using " + date + ". Use a format like this one: 2020-11-30";
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
        return orderListToString;
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
         see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://JAVA.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.something.JerseyProjectConnectionToDB</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>JerseyProjectConnectionToDB</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JerseyProjectConnectionToDB</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>JerseyProjectConnectionToDB</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.29.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.29.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.29.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have found that the problem was the method getOrder(), so i commented it and now works. My problem now is that when i let that method uncommented and i call to other methods, the code executes the method getOrder() instead of the method i called, what could be the problem?

Thank you for your help and time ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem. The method `@GET` dont accept `@FormParam`, you just need to use `@QueryParam` or `@PathParam`. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29789846/15633133